# Python Globalling to use and change in many functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, global-variables

I have made a program where there is are many values that are accessed and changed in many classes and functions. I want to know is how to use and change a variable without using global or only using it once. I used global around 20 times all throughout my code and it looks ugly and is annoying.

Comment: Pass the variables as arguments maybe?

Comment: I dont think you can neither you should othetrwise one will easily loose track of which one is global.

Comment: You could use environmet variables though. `os.env`

Comment: @saurabhbaid: Oh hell no. Super-duper-globaler-than-`global`, strings only? That is not a good way to implement your program's internal data structures.

Comment: Thanks, I used the idea in which a value is put in the `def __init__():` part of a class and is used throughout the code by `classname.variablename`.Some variables that didn't belong in any of the classes, I put  in an extra class called 'global variables'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas that I have is either to pass a reference of all these variables through functions. The other idea is to define classes containing the variables. The all the functions of the class have access to the values defined in the class and you don't need to pass them. Or you are passing pack of variables.